# How to execute a program with Kotlin and Arrow

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, io-monad, arrow-kt

I'm trying to learn a bit of Functional Programming using Kotlin and Arrow and in this way I've already read some blogposts like the following one: https://jorgecastillo.dev/kotlin-fp-1-monad-stack, which is good, I've understand the main idea, but when creating a *program*, I can't figure out how to run it.

Let me be more explicit:

I have the following piece of code:

```
typealias EitherIO<A, B> = EitherT<ForIO, A, B>

sealed class UserError(
        val message: String,
        val status: Int
) {
    object AuthenticationError : UserError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.reasonPhrase, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value())
    object UserNotFound : UserError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.reasonPhrase, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value())
    object InternalServerError : UserError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.reasonPhrase, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value())
}


@Component
class UserAdapter(
        private val myAccountClient: MyAccountClient
) {
    @Lazy
    @Inject
    lateinit var subscriberRepository: SubscriberRepository

    fun getDomainUser(ssoId: Long): EitherIO<UserError, User?> {
        val io = IO.fx {
            val userResource = getUserResourcesBySsoId(ssoId, myAccountClient).bind()
            userResource.fold(
                    { error -> Either.Left(error) },
                    { success ->
                        Either.right(composeDomainUserWithSubscribers(success, getSubscribersForUserResource(success, subscriberRepository).bind()))
                    })
        }
        return EitherIO(io)
    }

    fun composeDomainUserWithSubscribers(userResource: UserResource, subscribers: Option<Subscribers>): User? {
        return subscribers.map { userResource.toDomainUser(it) }.orNull()
    }
}

private fun getSubscribersForUserResource(userResource: UserResource, subscriberRepository: SubscriberRepository): IO<Option<Subscribers>> {
    return IO {
        val msisdnList = userResource.getMsisdnList()
        Option.invoke(subscriberRepository.findAllByMsisdnInAndDeletedIsFalse(msisdnList).associateBy(Subscriber::msisdn))
    }
}

private fun getUserResourcesBySsoId(ssoId: Long, myAccountClient: MyAccountClient): IO<Either<UserError, UserResource>> {
    return IO {
        val response = myAccountClient.getUserBySsoId(ssoId)
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val userResource = JacksonUtils.fromJsonToObject(response.body()?.string()!!, UserResource::class.java)
            Either.Right(userResource)
        } else {
            when (response.code()) {
                401 -> Either.Left(UserError.AuthenticationError)
                404 -> Either.Left(UserError.UserNotFound)
                else -> Either.Left(UserError.InternalServerError)
            }
        }
    }.handleError { Either.Left(UserError.InternalServerError) }
}
```

which, as you can see is accumulating some results into an IO monad. I should run this program using `unsafeRunSync()` from arrow, but on javadoc it's stated the following: `**NOTE** this function is intended for testing, it should never appear in your mainline production code!`. 
I should mention that I know about `unsafeRunAsync`, but in my case I want to be synchronous.

Thanks!

Comment: With monads you can't freely get the result of a monadic computation out of the monad. That is the fundamental trait of every monad. Instead of unwrapping the value you have a bunch of combinators to work with value inside the monadic context. However, if you exactly know what you are doing you can use `unsafeRunSync`, even in production code. But it should be the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: I want to provide a User as a result on an API call and I don't know how to provide the User instead of the EitherIO<UserError, User?>.

Comment: Make your API suspend and use `myIO.suspended()` to call on it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running `unsafeRunSync`, you should favor `unsafeRunAsync`.

If you have `myFun(): IO<A>` and want to run this, then you call `myFun().unsafeRunAsync(cb)` where `cb: (Either<Throwable, A>) -> Unit`.

For instance, if your function returns `IO<List<Int>>` then you can call

```
myFun().unsafeRunAsync {  /* it (Either<Throwable, List<Int>>) -> */
  it.fold(
    { Log.e("Foo", "Error! $it") },
    { println(it) })
}
```

This will run the program contained in the IO asynchronously and pass the result safely to the callback, which will log an error if the IO threw, and otherwise it will print the list of integers.

You should avoid `unsafeRunSync` for a number of reasons, discussed [here](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/effects/io/#unsaferunsync). It's blocking, it can cause crashes, it can cause deadlocks, and it can halt your application.

If you really want to run your IO as a blocking computation, then you can precede this with `attempt()` to have your `IO<A>` become an `IO<Either<Throwable, A>>` similar to the `unsafeRunAsync` callback parameter. At least then you won't crash.

But `unsafeRunAsync` is preferred. Also, make sure your callback passed to `unsafeRunAsync` won't throw any errors, at it's assumed it won't. [Docs](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/effects/io/#unsaferunasync).